# Enabling Cross Domain in Jersey - Facing runtime exception

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am following this [article](http://blog.usul.org/cors-compliant-rest-api-with-jersey-and-containerresponsefilter/) to make our Jersey to CORS complaint. So far I have implemented `ContainerResponseFilter` to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers to response. This is my snippet:

```
ResponseBuilder resp = Response.fromResponse(contResp.getResponse());
    resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    String reqHead = req.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

    if(null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals("")){
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
    }

    contResp.setResponse(resp.build());
```

And this is my web.xml contents:

```
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
         <param-value>com.test.ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

When I run I get this error:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
```

But if I run the same application with these config:

```
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.test.client</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

I am not getting any error. So this error is occuring only if I try to use ContainerResponseFilter. Can someone help me in resolving this issue?